# Responsive slide pannel with direction issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a responsive slide panel page here. How can i handle the direction of my slide panel page with both direction ( left to right, right to left) without any clash.

[image]

Comment: my fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/kannankds/cwjbexhw/

Comment: I don't understand, are you talking about text direction? Do you want to swap the panel to slide in from the right when direction is rtl?

Comment: want to swap the panel to slide in from the right when direction is rtl

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already have the directions defined in your `html`, so you will need to amend the below code to suit your needs:

**CSS:**

```
#panel {
    height: 450px;
    width: 200px;
    background: black;
    display: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: xx-large;
}

#panel[direction="ltr"] {
    float:left;
}

#panel[direction="rtl"] {
    float: right;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id='panel' direction="rtl">Pannel Details here</div>
```

or

```
<div id='panel' direction="ltr">Pannel Details here</div>
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwjbexhw/1/)

Comment: is any plugin available for this method?

Comment: Why do you need a plugin? It's very straightforward on what it's doing.